# Nginx proxy - too many redirects

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I dont know whats is wrong. When I try to access to www.befound.com.ar and I get this error on the browser: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This is my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    #tcp_nopush     on;


    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.befound.com.ar;

        location / {

            proxy_pass  http://www.befound.com.ar:8090/befound;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
proxy_set_header   Host 'HOST_WHICH_YOU WANT TO PROXY';
```

will help in 95% :)

Comment: You're the GOAT! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the service running on port 8090 does not have nginx configuration. So I think you need to change the proxy_pass host to localhost - `127.0.0.1:8090`

Comment: i did it but the problem persist

Comment: Also add a directive `proxy_redirect      off;` source -
 http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect